# Prove that $X \sim N(\sigma, \sigma^2)$ is a scale family

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing

Prove that $X \sim Normal(\sigma, \sigma^2)$ is a scale family. $\sigma>0$.

I'm not exactly sure how to approach this problem. I think I need to prove that the pdf of X is equal to $\frac1\sigma f(\frac x\sigma)$ for some function $f$, but I wrote out the pdf of X and I can't see any way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PDF of $X$ is
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(x - \sigma)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}.$$
Note that the exponent can be rewritten as $- \frac{(\frac{x}{\sigma} - 1)^2}{2}$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Oh wow, that's very clever, thanks! I'm pretty bad at figuring out how to rewrite things. So if I use that, I end up with the expression $\frac1\theta f(\frac x \theta)$ where $(\frac x \theta) \sim Normal(1, 1)$. This allows me to show what I'm trying to prove.